# How should I implement timer intervals into a code which has to execute the rotation of a servo motor at certain time of the day?

Tags: c++, mbed

I started a project where I am coding a pet feeder with a user interface on a mbed. I received a tip from a friend to use timer interface to implement it in my code to make it execute a servo motor at time set trough the user interface with the actual time also set trough the user interface too. But looking online I haven't been able to grasp the concept of timer interval and how to implement it to my code. thanks for any help given.

I already did a code for the my project which is way to complicated and not operational My code relied on variable which are equation to represent the amount of minutes since midnight.

```
#include "mbed.h"         // general mbed library
#include "C12832.h"       // Application Board LCD panel library

#define JOY_READ_TIME       0.200  // time (s) to read the joystick input
#define LCD_ROW_1           0      // pixel value for displaying row #1 text on the LCD panel
#define LCD_ROW_2          10
#define LCD_ROW_3          22

// Application Board LCD panel output pins
C12832 lcd(p5, p7, p6, p8, p11);

// Application Board joystick input pins
//              u   d   l   r   c
BusIn joystick(p15,p12,p13,p16,p14);
// for the bus: LSB            MSB
//DigitalIn joy_u(p15);
//DigitalIn joy_d(p12);
//DigitalIn joy_l(p13);
//DigitalIn joy_r(p16);
//DigitalIn joy_c(p14);

int Portion = 

int main () {

int T1_a = 0 //number of minutes since midnight for the first feeding time
int T1_b = T1_a / 60
int T1_c = T1_b * 60
int T1_d = T1_a - T1_c
int Q1 = 0

int T2_a = T1_a + 60 //number of minutes since midnight for the second feeding time
int T2_b = a / 60
int T2_c = e * 60
int T2_d = a - f
int Q2 = 0

int T0_a = 0 //number of minutes since midnight for the actual time
int T0_b = a / 60
int T0_c = e * 60
int T0_d = a - f

//situation 1 times
int Elip_1 = T1_a - T0_a
int Elip_2 = T2_a - T1_a
int Elip_29 = 1440 - T2_a
int Elip_3 = Elip_29 + T1_a

//situation 2 times
int Elip_1b = T2_a - T0_a
int Elip_19b = 1440 - T2_a
int Elip_2b = Elip_19b + T1_a
int Elip_3b = T0_a - T1_a

//situation 3 times
int Elip_09c = 1440 - T0_a
int Elip_1c = Elip_09c + T1_a
int Elip_2c = T2_a - T1_a
int Elip_3c = T2_a - T0_a

Start:
    lcd.cls();
    wait (200)
    
    While(1) {
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_1);
        lcd.printf("   Animal Feeder menu   \0");
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_3);
        lcd.printf("Next -->\0");
        
        if(joy_r.read()){
            break;
        }
    }
    
FeedingT1:
    lcd.cls();
    wait (200)
    
    While(1) {
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_1);
        lcd.printf("     Feeding Time 1     \0");
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_2);
        lcd.printf( T1_b, "h\0" T1_d, );
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_3);
        lcd.printf("<-- Back    Next -->\0");
        
        if((joy_u.read())&&(T1_a < 1320 )){
            T1_a = T1_a + 30;
            }
        if((joy_d.read())&&(T1_a > 0 )){
            T1_a = T1_a - 30;
        }
        if(joy_r.read()){
            break;
        }
        if(joy_l.read()){
            goto Start;
        }
    }
    
FeedingQ1:
    lcd.cls();
    wait (200)
    
    While(1) {
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_1);
        lcd.printf("   Feeding Quantity 1   \0");
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_2);
        lcd.printf( Q1, "Portion \0");
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_3);
        lcd.printf("<-- Back    Next -->\0");
        
        if((joy_u.read())&&(Q1 < 10 )){
            Q1 = Q1 + 1;
        }
        if((joy_d.read())&&(Q1 > 0 )){
            Q1 = Q1 - 1;
        }
        if(joy_r.read()){
            break;
        }
        if(joy_l.read()){
            goto FeedingT1;
        }
    }
    
FeedingT2:
    lcd.cls();
    wait (200)
    
    While(1) {
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_1);
        lcd.printf("     Feeding Time 2     \0");
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_2);
        lcd.printf( T2_b, "h\0" T2_d, );
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_3);
        lcd.printf("<-- Back    Next -->\0");
        
        if((joy_u.read())&&(T2_a < 1440 )){
            T2_a = T2_a + 30;
        }
        if((joy_d.read())&&(T2_a > 0 )){
            T2_a = T2_a - 30;
        }
        if(joy_r.read()){
            break;
        }
        if(joy_l.read()){
            goto FeedingQ1;
        }
    }
    
FeedingQ2:
    lcd.cls();
    wait (200)
    
    While(1) {
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_1);
        lcd.printf("   Feeding Quantity 2   \0");
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_2);
        lcd.printf( Q2, "Portion \0");
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_3);
        lcd.printf("<-- Back    Next -->\0");
        
        if((joy_u.read())&&(Q2 < 10 )){
            Q2 = Q2 + 1;
        }
        if((joy_d.read())&&(Q2 > 0 )){
            Q2 = Q2 - 1;
        }
        if(joy_r.read()){
            break;
        }
        if(joy_l.read()){
            goto FeedingT2;
        }
    }
    
Actualtime:
    lcd.cls();
    wait (200)
    
    While(1) {
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_1);
        lcd.printf("     Real time:     \0");
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_2);
        lcd.printf( T0_b, "h\0" T0_d, );
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_3);
        lcd.printf("<-- Back    Next -->\0");
        
        if((joy_u.read())&&(T3_a < 1440 )){
            T3_a = T3_a + 30;
        }
        if((joy_d.read())&&(T3_a > T1_a + 60 )){
            T3_a = T3_a - 30;
        }
        if(joy_r.read()){
            break;
        }
        if(joy_l.read()){
            goto FeedingQ2;
        }
    }
    
    
Situation1:

    if ( T0_a < T1_a ){
        lcd.cls();
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_2);
        lcd.printf("        Waiting        \0");
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_3);
        lcd.printf("Reset -->\0");

        int i = 0;
        while (i = 300 * Elip_1) {
            wait (200)
            
            if(joy_r.read()){
                goto Start;
            }
        i++;
        }
    
        if ( Q1 > 0 ){
            lcd.cls();
            lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_2);
            lcd.printf("      Bon appetit      \0");
            int i = 0;
            while (i = Q1 * Portion) {
            
                //make the motor spin for a portion
                
            i++;
            }   
        }
        else {
            goto SkipS1Q1;
        }
        
        SkipS1Q1:

        lcd.cls();
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_2);
        lcd.printf("        Waiting        \0");
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_3);
        lcd.printf("Reset -->\0");

        int i = 0;
        while (i = 300 * Elip_2) {
            wait (200)
            
            if(joy_r.read()){
                goto Start;
            }
        i++;
        }
        
        if ( Q2 > 0 ){
            lcd.cls();
            lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_2);
            lcd.printf("      Bon appetit      \0");
            int i = 0;
            while (i = Q2 * Portion) {
            
                //make the motor spin for a portion
                
            i++;
            }
        }
        else {
            goto SkipS1Q2;
        }
        
        SkipS1Q2:
        
        lcd.cls();
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_2);
        lcd.printf("        Waiting        \0");
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_3);
        lcd.printf("Reset -->\0");  
        int i = 0;
        while (i = 300 * Elip_3) {
            wait (200)
            
            if(joy_r.read())
                goto Start;
        i++;
        }
        goto Situation1;
        
    }
    
Situation2:

    else if ( T0_a > T1_a && T0_a < T2_a ){
        lcd.cls();
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_2);
        lcd.printf("        Waiting        \0");
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_3);
        lcd.printf("Reset -->\0");

        int i = 0;
        while (i = 300 * Elip_1b) {
            wait (200)
            
            if(joy_r.read()){
                goto Start;
            }
        i++;
        }
    
        if ( Q1 > 0 ){
            lcd.cls();
            lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_2);
            lcd.printf("      Bon appetit      \0");
            int i = 0;
            while (i = Q1 * Portion) {
            
                //make the motor spin for a portion
                
            i++;
            }   
        }
        else {
            goto SkipS2Q1;
        }
        
        SkipS2Q1:

        lcd.cls();
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_2);
        lcd.printf("        Waiting        \0");
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_3);
        lcd.printf("Reset -->\0");

        int i = 0;
        while (i = 300 * Elip_2b) {
            wait (200)
            
            if(joy_r.read()){
                goto Start;
            }
        i++;
        }
        
        if ( Q2 > 0 ){
            lcd.cls();
            lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_2);
            lcd.printf("      Bon appetit      \0");
            int i = 0;
            while (i = Q2 * Portion) {
            
                //make the motor spin for a portion
                
            i++;
            }
        }
        else {
            goto SkipS2Q2;
        }
        
        SkipS2Q2:
        
        lcd.cls();
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_2);
        lcd.printf("        Waiting        \0");
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_3);
        lcd.printf("Reset -->\0");  
        int i = 0;
        while (i = 300 * Elip_3b) {
            wait (200)
            
            if(joy_r.read())
                goto Start;
        i++;
        }
        goto Situation2;
        
    }
    
Situation3:
    
    else if ( T0_a > T1_a && T0_a > T2_a ){
        lcd.cls();
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_2);
        lcd.printf("        Waiting        \0");
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_3);
        lcd.printf("Reset -->\0");

        int i = 0;
        while (i = 300 * Elip_1c) {
            wait (200)
            
            if(joy_r.read()){
                goto Start;
            }
        i++;
        }
    
        if ( Q1 > 0 ){
            lcd.cls();
            lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_2);
            lcd.printf("      Bon appetit      \0");
            int i = 0;
            while (i = Q1 * Portion) {
            
                //make the motor spin for a portion
                
            i++;
            }   
        }
        else {
            goto SkipS3Q1;
        }
        
        SkipS3Q1:

        lcd.cls();
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_2);
        lcd.printf("        Waiting        \0");
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_3);
        lcd.printf("Reset -->\0");

        int i = 0;
        while (i = 300 * Elip_2c) {
            wait (200)
            
            if(joy_r.read()){
                goto Start;
            }
        i++;
        }
        
        if ( Q2 > 0 ){
            lcd.cls();
            lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_2);
            lcd.printf("      Bon appetit      \0");
            int i = 0;
            while (i = Q2 * Portion) {
            
                //make the motor spin for a portion
                
            i++;
            }
        }
        else {
            goto SkipS3Q2;
        }
        
        SkipS3Q2:
        
        lcd.cls();
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_2);
        lcd.printf("        Waiting        \0");
        lcd.locate(0,LCD_ROW_3);
        lcd.printf("Reset -->\0");  
        int i = 0;
        while (i = 300 * Elip_3c) {
            wait (200)
            
            if(joy_r.read())
                goto Start;
        i++;
        }
        goto Situation3;
        
    }
        
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't understand how you expect this code to work.  The user interface is slow, unresponsive and not user friendly, and none of the computations exposed at the top of main() are useful.  This is far from being operational.

Comment: thank you for your input, tho that is the subject of my question i want to get rid of those computation with the use of timer interval but i am not finding anything online which i understand

Comment: and the user face is to be done on a mbed application board (LCD panel, RGB LED, IMU, speaker, 2 pots, joystick) which does not have a lot of space to make a more intutive user interface with my knowledge i am open to any suggestions